# I'm having DPC latency issues with my computer

Tags: audio, windows-8.1, latency, dpc

The LatencyMon report will be added to the end of this. I recently got a modi and magni amp and dac combo and I've had audio stuttering issues.

Here is a image of all my drivers [image: Here is a image of all my drivers.] I was told that I should disable certain drivers to help with DPC issues. I need help choosing which ones to disable. If you have any suggestions on how to fix this issue please let me know. I can also provide more information if necessary.

[Here is the latencymon report](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=8iBbjpx9)

edit: [Here is the USB drivers unhidden](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wlXvB.png)

Comment: You generally disable one driver at a time to see if that reduces DPC latency or gets rid of spikes. After finding the problem driver(s) you use other hardware for a similar function, update or revert to a version of the driver without the problem and/or search google for others with the same device/driver problems. See: http://www.thesycon.de/deu/latency_check.shtml

Comment: I'm afraid I have duplicate drivers. I saw in another forum that someone solved their DPC latency issue by disabling duplicate drivers that had been installed. I'm not sure which ones would be duplicates though...

Comment: capture a xperf trace (close latencymon before running xperf) and give me the file: http://www.msfn.org/board/index.php?showtopic=140263 Zip and uplaod the file (Dropbox, SkyDrive)